# How to account for temporal autocorrelation in BRT models?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial, biostatistics, boosting

I have GPS data (every 20 minutes) on storks flight heights and am modelling several predictors using Boosted Random Trees (using `gbm` and `dismo` packages in R). To account for spatial autocorrelation I used the Residuals Autocovariate (RAC) approach using `autocov_dist` to create the autocovariate from model residuals (I also computed correlograms and tested Moran's I).

I am wondering what are my options for testing and accounting for temporal autocorrelation in BRTrees ... I looked into durbin watson test, but didn't find a way to use it in this case.

Any suggestions on how to deal with temporal autocorrelation in BRTrees?

Comment: Can you please give a few more details about the Residuals Autocovariate was used to inform the GBM model?

Comment: The residuals autocovariate was computed from a 2km distance around each point with a inverse weights matrix. What kind information do you need?